# How to identify key in hashmap when it looks like :entry.getBname.getTitle()"

Tags: java, hashmap, key-value, put

When I was doing hashmap coding, I hit a bump to identify key, an example as follow:

```
public void addBE(BookEntry entry)
{
library.put(entry.getBname().getTitle(), entry);
}
```

So for this example, is `getBname()` or `getTitle` the key for this?, and entry should be the value right? But entry represents a class, so it means everything in entry is the value?

Thanks for clarifing my doubt.

FYI: BookEntry class：

```
public class BookEntry{
private BookName bname;
private Writer wname;
private BookID b_id;

public BookEntry(BookName bname, Writer wname, BookID b_id)
{
this.bname = bname;
this.wname = wname;
this.b_id = b_id;
}

public BookName getBname()
{
return bname;
}
public Writer getWname()
{
return wname;
}
public BookID getBookID()
{
return b_id;
}
public String toString()
{
return bname.toString() + " " + wname.toString() + " " + b_id.toString();
}

public static BookEntry enterBE()
{
BookName bname = BookName.enterName();
Writer wname = Writer.enterWriter();
BookID b_id = BookID.enterID();
return new BookEntry(bname, wname, b_id);
}
}
```

Comment: The syntax for put is `put(key, value)`. Everything before the comma is the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is the title, i.e. the output of getTitle(). It would be the same as:

```
String titleKey = entry.getBname().getTitle(); // assuming title is a String, but it could be any type
library.put(titleKey, entry);
```

Comment: But why don't we just put `entry.getTitle()` ?

Comment: Does BookEntry have that method? If so, you can go for it, assuming that the semantic is the same (i.e. it is the same title). If BookEntry does not have that method, you cannot, of course. You may also consider using Bname as key (key=entry.getBname()), if its semantic i reasonable for making it a key. If you post the BookEntry class, I can try to be more helpful.

Comment: I have just posted my BookEntry class

Comment: And which method you are refering to?

Comment: As you can see, BookEntry does not have a getTitle method. The book title is part of the BookName class, which is a different class. Therefore, to access the title, you first get the BookName instance, then access the title. If you correctly ovverride the equals method in BookName, you may also use the BookName instance as key in the map: key=entry.getBname(). Check  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)

Comment: But then can we just get title from BookName class?  `public void addBE(BookEntry entry` means add sth to BookEntry?

Comment: I think you want to take a look at the fundamentals: Object, Class, Method. Everything will be much more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your understanding is correct. The whole entry class is a value.

In the below line

```
library.put(entry.getBname().getTitle(), entry);
```

`entry.getBname().getTitle()` --> key

`entry` ---> value.

Answer (score 0):

In `Java` `Map<Key,Value>`.

Now here

```
library.put(entry.getBname().getTitle(), entry); // library is your Map
```

And what ever the value return from   `entry.getBname().getTitle()` is the `Key` and `entry` is the value.